# table.getdata returns an empty string

Tags: tabulator

I want to save the table to a text file after making changes. When I click the save button tbldata is empty and my text file is overwritten and blank.

I have tested the button with: var tbldata = JSON.stringify([{"id":1, "name":"Bob"}]) and it works.

I am assuming I am using table.getData incorrectly. Where and how in my button function should var tbldata = table.getdata be located?

I cannot find a specific example in the documentation

```js
 <button class="button" id="save-data" >Save Data</button>
 
    <script>
        //create Tabulator on DOM element
        var table = new Tabulator("#meetinfo-table", {
      height:200, // set height of table (in CSS or here)
        selectable:true, //make rows selectable        
      layout:"fitDataFill",//fit columns to fit data and width of table (optional)
  //Sort data decending
  initialSort:[
   {column: "meetdate", dir:"desc"}],
  //Define Table Columns   
  columns:[ 
       {title:"Meeting Date", field:"meetdate", width:150, editor:"input"},
       {title:"Topic", field:"topic", align:"left", editor:"input"},
       {title:"Speaker", field:"speaker", editor:"input"},
       {title:"Room", field:"room", editor:"input"},
         {title:"CE", field:"ce", align:"left", editor:"input"},
       {title:"RSVP Survey Code", field:"rsvpcode",editor: "input"},   
       {title:"RSVP Due Date", field:"rsvpduedate", editor:"input"},
      ], 
         }); 
                     
        //Saves entire table to JSON encoded string
  var button = document.getElementById("save-data");
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
  var tbldata = table.getdata;
    
  var request= new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
  request.open("POST", "process.php");
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  //request.send(tbldata);
  });
  
  //loads data into the table
  table.setData('meetinfo_array.txt');
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues there, it is ***getData*** not ***getdata*** and you a not actually calling the function because you are missing the parenthesis after the function name. It should be:

```
var tbldata = table.getData();
```